# Error Installing Truffle

Tags: truffle

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

---

I am following this guide (https://www.codeooze.com/blockchain/ethereum-dev-environment-2019/) to install Ganache, npm, and then Truffle.

Everything is fine till I execute

`sudo npm install -g truffle`

I get error,

```
/usr/local/bin/truffle -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js

> truffle@5.1.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/solidity/.config/truffle/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

......

```
Error: Error while attempting to download and cache solc 0.5.8: Command failed: node ./build/cli.bundled.js obtain --solc=0.5.8
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/solidity/.config/truffle/config.json'
You don't have access to this file.
```

I checked GitHub for issue, and I'm not understanding how to use nvm (other than execute `nvm install stable`)

Here are my software versions

```
solidity@solidity:~$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.5.13+commit.5b0b510c.Linux.g++
solidity@solidity:~$ npm --version
3.8.6
solidity@solidity:~$ nvm --version
0.35.1
solidity@solidity:~$ node --version
v5.12.0
```

Short of uninstalling everything and reinstalling everything, how to fix this?

Comment: One solution could be to run ``chmod 777 /usr``. However, I would keep it as plan Z as it may not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out (please feel free to chime in)

I followed instructions to install nodejs via nvm here, https://www.ostechnix.com/install-node-js-linux/

Then I executed `npm install -g truffle`

Now when I run `truffle version`, I get

```
Truffle v5.1.2 (core: 5.1.2)
Solidity v0.5.12 (solc-js)
Node v13.2.0
Web3.js v1.2.2
```